# How to process an If statement whilst in an array and an echo

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

This is my first post as I've been trying hard to find my own way but my brain is about to explode and I would really appreciate your help before that occurs.  I have a while loop that outputs the required data but within that while loop I want to check if the session user == user_id, if that statement is true then I want to add a link within the loop so the user can edit their post.  I have tried so many variations, there are too many to list (some come close and others are disasters)  this is what I have currently which is incorrect but would really appreciate some advice.  At first I had my if calc embedded in my echo which to my surprise recognised the listing creator but the rest of my loop would then fail so now I've tried to add it as a $IsUser before the echo and then calling that function within the echo but that is not working either.  I apologies if this is basic stuff or my thought processes are completely way off.

```
<?php
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("../php_includes/db_conx.php");
//Run a select query
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT listing.user_id, listing.id, users.username,     listing.date_created, listing.status, listing.category, listing.country, listing.date_deadline, listing.date_start, listing.title, listing.description
FROM listing
INNER JOIN users
ON listing.user_id=users.id
ORDER BY date_created DESC");

//Is User listing creator
//$isUser = "no";
if($string1==$string2){
    $isUser = '<a href="listing_add.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">Edit Listing</a>';
}

//Run listing loop
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$string1 = $row['user_id'];
$string2 = $_SESSION['userid'];
  {
  echo '
    <div id=listings>
    <div id=img><br>No image to display</div>
        <div id=row>
            <div id=title><a href="listing_disp.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">'. $row['title'] .'</a></div>  
        </div>
        <div id=row>
            <div id=description>'. $row['description'] .'</div>
            <div id=created>Added: '. date('jS M Y',strtotime($row['date_created'])) .'</div>
            <div id=deadline>Deadline: '. date('jS M Y',strtotime($row['date_deadline'])) .'</div>
            <div id=category>Category: <a href="index.php?'. $row['category'].'">'. $row['category'] .'</a></div>   
            <div id=user>User: &nbsp;<a href="index.php?'. $row['user_id'].'">'. $row['username'].'</a> </div>      
        </div>
        <div id=row>
        <div id=edit>'.$isUser.'</div>
            <div id=country>'. $row['country'] .'</div>


        </div>
  </div>
  ';
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove condition from top of page and try following

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $string1 = $row['user_id'];
    if($string1 == $_SESSION['userid'])
      {
        $isUser = '<a href="listing_add.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">Edit Listing</a>';
      }else{
        $isUser = '';
      }
      echo '
        <div id=listings>
        <div id=img><br>No image to display</div>
            <div id=row>
                <div id=title><a href="listing_disp.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">'. $row['title'] .'</a></div>  
            </div>
            <div id=row>
                <div id=description>'. $row['description'] .'</div>
                <div id=created>Added: '. date('jS M Y',strtotime($row['date_created'])) .'</div>
                <div id=deadline>Deadline: '. date('jS M Y',strtotime($row['date_deadline'])) .'</div>
                <div id=category>Category: <a href="index.php?'. $row['category'].'">'. $row['category'] .'</a></div>   
                <div id=user>User: &nbsp;<a href="index.php?'. $row['user_id'].'">'. $row['username'].'</a> </div>      
            </div>
            <div id=row>
            <div id=edit>'.$isUser.'</div>
                <div id=country>'. $row['country'] .'</div>


            </div>
      </div>
      ';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! It worked like a charm.  I'm now going to try and understand the process.  Many thanks once again.

Comment: CORRECTION - I got carried away with my excitement. It works being hat the link is displayed and the loop continues but the link is being displayed for all rows and not just where the $row['user_id'] == $_SESSION['userid'] which doesn't make sense.  I'll have a play but if anyone has an idea why that would be great.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @TimChapman I have updated code.. please use this latest one.. and please correct my ans. so i get more points :P

Comment: Many thanks @w3b for getting back so quickly and many thanks for updating.  This time it worked as I hoped and I learnt something. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that if inside the while, also in your code the `{` after the while is placed incorrect.

Since `$string2` stays the same you can define it outside the loop, but you can't do the same with `$string1` because it needs the current data from `$row`

```
$string2 = $_SESSION['userid'];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $string1 = $row['user_id'];
    if ($string1==$string2) { /* do what you have to do */ }
    // output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `if` statement within the `while` loop. Also noticed that I changed your id's to classes as **you don't want to be echoing out duplicate id's in your DOM**.

I also renamed your variable from `$isUser` to `$editLink` and **made sure that it's cleared out for subsequent loop iterations.**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['user_id'] == $_SESSION['userid'] {
        $editLink = '<a href="listing_add.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit Listing</a>';
    } else {
        $editLink = '';
    }

    echo '
    <div class="listings">
    <div class=lsitings-img"><br />No image to display</div>
        <div class="listings-row">
            <div class="listings-title"><a href="listing_disp.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">'. $row['title'] .'</a></div>  
        </div>
        <div class="listings-row">
            <div class="istings-row-description">'. $row['description'] .'</div>
            <div class="istings-row-created">Added: '. date('jS M Y',strtotime($row['date_created'])) .'</div>
            <div class="istings-row-deadline">Deadline: '. date('jS M Y',strtotime($row['date_deadline'])) .'</div>
            <div class="istings-row-category">Category: <a href="index.php?'. $row['category'].'">'. $row['category'] .'</a></div>   
            <div class="istings-row-user">User: &nbsp;<a href="index.php?'. $row['user_id'].'">'. $row['username'].'</a> </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="listings-row">
            <div class="listings-edit">' . $editLink . '</div>
            <div class="listings-country">' . $row['country'] . '</div>
        </div>
  </div>
  ';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up in regard to my div classes.